# Python group by and find find first sequence that matches a criterion

Tags: python, numpy, functional-programming, pandas-groupby

So I am a beginner and I found many posts about how to find first sequence hat matches a criterion but I don't know how to combine it with "group by" function and displaying it new column.

I need to group data by column "Group" and find the first value that is >0 and show it in a now column repeatedly in every row for the group.

Input:

```py
df_input = pd.DataFrame({
    "Group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
    "Value": [0, 1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0, 3, 0]
})
```

Output:

```py
df_output = pd.DataFrame({
    "Group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
    "Value": [0, 1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0, 3, 0],
    "First sequence": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
})
```

Comment: What if there is no value in the group that is greater than 1?

Comment: Also please include the sample of you dataframe in the question which can be copied and not just the pictures.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Why don't you take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I think it could be useful for you and the community.

Comment: In your output data frame, you have 1 in every row for A, but 1 is not greater than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solves your problem as you described it.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_input = pd.DataFrame({
    "Group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
    "Value": [0, 1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0, 3, 0]
})

def greater_than(array, lower_bound=1):
    condition_fulfiled = (array > lower_bound)
    is_greater = condition_fulfiled.any()

    if is_greater:
        return array[np.argmax(condition_fulfiled)]
    else:
        return None


df_input_grouped = df_input.groupby("Group")
df_input_grouped = df_input_grouped.agg([greater_than])


df_input["First sequence"] = None

for group, value in zip(df_input_grouped.index, df_input_grouped.Value.greater_than):
    df_input["First sequence"][df_input.Group==group] = value

df_input
```

If you want to have the result from your result `data frame` you just have to change the function `greater_than` to

```py
def greater_than(array, lower_bound=1):
    condition_fulfiled = (array >= lower_bound)
    is_greater = condition_fulfiled.any()

    if is_greater:
        return array[np.argmax(condition_fulfiled)]
    else:
        return None
```